# How can I embed and align in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, embed

I'm trying to embed an imageView, a label inside a View.
When I come to add the stackView with the View, I keep on getting red lines and cannot embed it.

I basically am trying to line it all up so when I flip the phone it all syncs.

[image: Click me for pic]

[image: Click me for pic]

Comment: can you share demo project ?

Comment: I have taken 2 screen shots and added them with the question. Click where it says entre image here. Is there any other way to share pics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no need to create additional `UIView` instance to wrap all subviews together when you're already using a `UIStackView`. Try to put both the label and the image view inside the stack view, then provide constraints for the stack view itself.

To provide the constrains for a stack view you need to tell the auto layout engine first how you want it to be laid out. From the screenshots provided, I assume you'd like to have it centered in the middle of the screen. To achieve that, set the stack view's `centerX` and `centerY` constraints equal to `centerX` and `centerY` of the view controller's `view`. The width and height of the stack view should be calculated automatically based on its inner views intrinsic content size.

Comment: hey mate, im new to all this, im going to try this thank you.